# Combining a histogram with a scatterplot of separate means in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data sets. One is summarized with nine means with confidence intervals for age (see plot below). The second is raw data that contain thousands of lines long. The relationship between the two data sets is that they are from the same Islands.
[Mean Age Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrffA.png)
[Size Frequency Histograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oKBD.png)
I would like to add the mean ages with CI's to the frequency histogram and include a second x-axis opposite of "Size" for "Age (yr)".

These are the data frames I'm using.
[Mean Age Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pKcV.png)
[Size Count Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkZME.png)

So far I have this but I can't get it to work around the error I keep getting:

```r
#Generating data frames to test with.
Island_List <- c("KIN", "PAL", "TAB", "KIR", "MAL", "STA", "MIL", "VOS", "FLI")
Size_List <- c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35)
Fish_Mean_Age <- c(6.488024,7.325288,10.184943,12.843898,6.137257,4.814145,4.421930,3.138250,1.987950)
Lower95 <- c(6.065302,6.868382,9.748409,11.964554,5.717515,4.312715,3.819582,2.294968,1.298495)
Upper95 <- c(6.910745,7.782194,10.621477,13.723241,6.556999,5.315575,5.024278,3.981531,2.677405)

Island <- sample(Island_List, 3374, replace = TRUE)
Size <- sample (Size_List, 3374, replace = TRUE)

df1 <- data.frame(Island,Size)
df2 <- data.frame(Island_List, Fish_Mean_Age, Lower95, Upper95)

#The code I've been trying so far: 

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Size, fill = factor(Island)))+
    geom_histogram(bins = 25)+
    geom_point(x = df2$Fish_Mean_Age*2, y = df2$Island_List)+
    scale_x_continuous(name = "Count", sec.axis = (~./2))+
    coord_flip()+
    facet_wrap(Island ~., ncol = 10)+
    theme_dark()+
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

This is the error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
> (3374): x and y

I think I get why I'm getting the error, but not sure how to resolve it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you Ronak, I will add it. Not 100% sure I can have expected output beyond what I'm describing but I will sure try.